# /sys/kernel/slab/ contents :at-0000016 :t-0000040 :dt-0001024 etc. meaning

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

While examining some memory leak I found a strange for me contents of `/sys/kernel/slab/` directory. It contains a list of directories:

```
:at-0000016  :t-0000040  :t-0000832
:at-0000032  :t-0000048  :t-0000896
:at-0000040  :t-0000056  :t-0000960
:at-0000048  :t-0000064  :t-0001024
:at-0000064  :t-0000072  :t-0001088
:at-0000072  :t-0000080  :t-0001888
:at-0000104  :t-0000088  :t-0002048
:at-0000128  :t-0000096  :t-0002096
:at-0000136  :t-0000104  :t-0002112
:at-0000144  :t-0000112  :t-0002944
:at-0000192  :t-0000120  :t-0003312
:at-0000256  :t-0000128  :t-0004096
:at-0000312  :t-0000160  :t-0008192
:dt-0000008  :t-0000184  ...
:dt-0000016  :t-0000192
:dt-0000032  :t-0000208
:dt-0000064  :t-0000216
:dt-0000096  :t-0000224
:dt-0000128  :t-0000232
:dt-0000192  :t-0000256
:dt-0000256  :t-0000312
:dt-0000512  :t-0000320
:dt-0001024  :t-0000328
:dt-0002048  :t-0000344
:dt-0004096  :t-0000384
:dt-0008192  :t-0000400
:t-0000008   :t-0000448
:t-0000016   :t-0000512
:t-0000024   :t-0000640
:t-0000032   :t-0000704
```

with specific names. I understand that these directories could represent some common slabs with appropriate sizes in bytes and that some other normally named slabs are maybe just aliases for this basic slabs. By the way, these entries aren't listed in output of `/proc/slabinfo`.
So what is the meaning of these directories? What are the prefixes `:at-`, `:dt-` and `:t-`? How can this be interpreted?